# Check if one number is contained in other number

Tags: c, function, numbers

The task is to check if the second input number is contained in the first input number. For example:
Input: 2357 35 (YES), 2365 35 (NO). I had this idea to store the digits of the first number in an array and then see if the digits are the same as the digits of the second number and if the difference between their array indexes is 1. But, I am having a trouble writing this in my code and that is why the part of my function is empty. I am a beginner, and I really hope you could help me to write the part with checking if the digits are the same and if the difference between their indexes is 1. Using string is not permitted.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    int number_within_number(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
       int digit,i=0,counter=0,array[10];
       while(a){
               digit=a%10;
               array[i]=digit;
               a/=10;
               i++;
               counter++;
               }
       while(b){
              digit=b%10;
              array[i]=digit;
              b/=10;
              i++;
              counter++;
               }
      for(i=0;i<counter;i++){?
          return 1; }  
      return 0;
  }
   int main(){
              int a,b;
              printf("Enter a: ");
              scanf("%d", &a);
              printf("Enter b: ");
              scanf("%d", &b);
              if(number_within_number(a,b)==1)
              printf("YES");
              if(number_within_number(a,b)==0)
              printf("NO");
              }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question about this code? "I'm having trouble" is difficult to find an answer to.

Comment: Maybe you want [`strstr()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html)? Using `strstr()` would be better to get the data from the user as a string in the first place.

Comment: Your code is invalid and shouldn't compile, `array[i]=k;` what is k? `for(i=0;i<counter;i++){? return 1; }` this is not valid syntax.

Comment: @a.Li I changed k to digit, and the code cannot compile because I left for loop empty since I don't know how to continue.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I edited the question. I am asking for help with my function. I don't know how to continue and write my idea in code.

Comment: @pmg Using string is not allowed.

Comment: Is there a usable limit for `b`? something like "b is always less than 100"

Comment: "Asking for help" is unfortunately (for you) [also not a question that is suitable for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: So, you cannot test whether a number contains `"04"` (like `404`) :o

Comment: @pmg No, I can't

Answer (score 1):

The easy/obvious way is to use `sprintf` to get a digit string from a number. Then, use `strstr` to see if the smaller number (e.g. `needle`) is contained in the larger number (e.g. `haystack`).

Creating arrays of digits is a similar approach.

**But ...**

There is a more direct approach that may be faster (6x faster).

1. Calculate the power of 10 that is greater than `needle`. (e.g. `10, 100, 1000`, etc.). Call this `mod10`.
2. Compute `haystack % mod10`.
3. We have a match if this equals `needle`.
4. If not, divide `haystack` by 10
5. Repeat as long as `haystack >= needle`

For example, for `2357 35`, `mod10` will be 100:

```
2357 % 100 == 57
235 % 100  == 35
```

For `2365 35`, `mod10` is 100:

```
2365 % 100 == 65
236 % 100  == 36
```

---

Anyway here's some code with some testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_lvl,_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (opt_d >= _lvl) \
            printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

int opt_d;
int opt_n;

// match_mod10 -- fast/direct
int
match_mod10(int hay,int need)
{
    int mod10;
    int haymod;
    int match = 0;

    for (mod10 = 1;  mod10 <= need;  mod10 *= 10);
    dbgprt(2,"mod10=%d\n",mod10);

    while (hay >= need) {
        haymod = hay % mod10;

        dbgprt(2,"hay=%d need=%d haymod=%d\n",hay,need,haymod);

        match = (haymod == need);
        if (match)
            break;

        hay /= 10;
    }

    return match;
}

// match_strstr -- reference implementation
int
match_strstr(int hay,int need)
{
    char haybuf[100];
    char needbuf[100];
    int match;

    sprintf(haybuf,"%d",hay);
    sprintf(needbuf,"%d",need);

    match = (strstr(haybuf,needbuf) != NULL);

    return match;
}

void
dotest(int hay,int need)
{
    int strflg;
    int modflg;
    int fail;

    // get reference value
    if (opt_n)
        strflg = 0;
    else
        strflg = match_strstr(hay,need);

    modflg = match_mod10(hay,need);
    if (opt_n)
        fail = 0;
    else
        fail = (strflg != modflg);

    if (opt_d || fail) {
        printf("%d %d -- strflg=%d modflg=%d %s\n",
            hay,need,strflg,modflg,fail ? "FAIL" : "PASS");
        if (fail)
            exit(1);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'd':
            opt_d = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;
        case 'n':
            opt_n = ! opt_n;
            break;
        }
    }

    do {
        int hay;
        int need;

        if (argc == 2) {
            hay = atoi(argv[0]);
            need = atoi(argv[1]);
            dotest(hay,need);
            break;
        }

        for (need = 2;  need <= 99;  ++need) {
            for (hay = 1;  hay < 1000000;  ++hay)
                dotest(hay,need);
        }

        printf("FINAL: %d %d\n",hay,need);
    } while (0);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

From Aman:

> with Craig Estey's idea, By his idea, you can easily code without the array and it will be more efficient. Here I have written the function.

It's flattering to have someone use and adapt code written for an answer for their answer.

I decided to benchmark the various algorithms.

Although Aman's adaptation seems fast, it actually slows things down. It was slower than every other method except the [reference] `strstr`.

Both my algorithm and Aman's have the same final loop.

But, `mod10` algorithm used a single loop that used a multiply. Aman's used a divide [which is slower than multiply].

And, then, it used `pow`--this is *expensive*. This can be replaced with  a loop with a multiply to get some speedup.

I modified the original `mod10` method to use caching/memoization of the `mod10` value. This provided some further speedup

Here's the benchmark output:

```
HAY: 1 1000000
NEED: 2 99
TESTS: strstr strstr2 array array2 mod10 aman1 aman2 mod10b

Sorted:
23.726686639 strstr -- sprintf/strstr reference
13.021570598 strstr2 (1.822x faster) (1.822x faster) -- sprintf/strstr (cached)
3.827459623 aman1 (3.402x faster) (6.199x faster) -- Aman's original (with pow)
3.265761858 array (1.172x faster) (7.265x faster) -- decode numbers into arrays
2.875820484 array2 (1.136x faster) (8.250x faster) -- arrays (cached)
2.826747834 aman2 (1.017x faster) (8.394x faster) -- Aman's modified (multiply)
1.873383061 mod10 (1.509x faster) (12.665x faster) -- mod10 algorithm
1.803308872 mod10b (1.039x faster) (13.157x faster) -- mod10 (with caching)
```

Here's the benchmark code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define XFLUSH \
    do { \
        if (! hangflg) \
            break; \
        fputc('\n',stdout); \
        hangflg = 0; \
    } while (0)

int hangflg;

#define dbgok(_lvl) \
    _dbgok(#_lvl[0])

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_lvl,_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (! dbgok(_lvl)) \
            break; \
        XFLUSH; \
        printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

typedef long long tsc_t;
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef unsigned char byte;

int opt_c;
int opt_q;
byte opt_d[256];

int haylim[2];
int needlim[2];
int mod10b_redo;

int outflg = 1;

#define outprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (outflg) \
            printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)

static inline byte
_dbgok(int lvl)
{

    return opt_d[(byte) lvl];
}

tsc_t
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    return tsc;
}

double
tscsec(tsc_t tsc)
{
    double sec;

    sec = tsc;
    sec /= 1e9;

    return sec;
}

// match_mod10 -- fast/direct
int
match_mod10(int hay,int need)
{
    int mod10;
    int haymod;
    int match = 0;

    for (mod10 = 1;  mod10 <= need;  mod10 *= 10);
    dbgprt(L,"mod10=%d\n",mod10);

    while (hay >= need) {
        haymod = hay % mod10;

        dbgprt(L,"hay=%d need=%d haymod=%d\n",hay,need,haymod);

        match = (haymod == need);
        if (match)
            break;

        hay /= 10;
    }

    return match;
}

// match_mod10b -- fast/direct (cached)
int
match_mod10b(int hay,int need)
{
    static int limlo = 0;
    static int limhi = -1;
    int mod10;
    int haymod;
    int match = 0;

    if ((need >= limhi) || (need < limlo)) {
        limlo = 1;
        limhi = 1;
        for (mod10 = 1;  mod10 <= need;) {
            limlo = mod10;
            mod10 *= 10;
            limhi = mod10;
        }
        ++mod10b_redo;
        dbgprt(N,"DEBUG: need=%d mod10=%d limlo=%d limhi=%d mod10b_redo=%d\n",
            need,mod10,limlo,limhi,mod10b_redo);
    }
    mod10 = limhi;

    while (hay >= need) {
        haymod = hay % mod10;

        dbgprt(L,"hay=%d need=%d haymod=%d\n",hay,need,haymod);

        match = (haymod == need);
        if (match)
            break;

        hay /= 10;
    }

    return match;
}

// match_strstr -- reference implementation
int
match_strstr(int hay,int need)
{
    char haybuf[100];
    char needbuf[100];
    int match;

    sprintf(haybuf,"%d",hay);
    sprintf(needbuf,"%d",need);

    match = (strstr(haybuf,needbuf) != NULL);

    return match;
}

// match_strstr -- reference implementation (cached)
int
match_strstr2(int hay,int need)
{
    static int hayold = -1;
    static char haybuf[100];
    static int needold = -1;
    static char needbuf[100];
    int match;

    if (hay != hayold) {
        sprintf(haybuf,"%d",hay);
        hayold = hay;
    }

    if (need != needold) {
        sprintf(needbuf,"%d",need);
        needold = need;
    }

    match = (strstr(haybuf,needbuf) != NULL);

    return match;
}

int
_match_array(int hay,char *haybuf)
{
    char *hayp;

    for (hayp = haybuf;  hay != 0;  ++hayp) {
        *hayp = hay % 10;
        hay /= 10;
    }

    return (hayp - haybuf);
}

// match_array -- array
int
match_array(int hay,int need)
{
    int match = 0;

    char haybuf[100];
    int haylen = _match_array(hay,haybuf);

    char needbuf[100];
    int needlen = _match_array(need,needbuf);

    char *haye = &haybuf[haylen - needlen];
    for (char *hayp = haybuf;  hayp <= haye;  ++hayp) {
        for (int needidx = 0;  needidx < needlen;  ++needidx) {
            match = (hayp[needidx] == needbuf[needidx]);
            dbgprt(L,"match_array: TRY needidx=%d hayp=%d needbuf=%d match=%d\n",
                needidx,hayp[needidx],needbuf[needidx],match);
            if (! match)
                break;
        }
        if (match)
            break;
    }

    return match;
}

// match_array2 -- array (cached)
int
match_array2(int hay,int need)
{
    int match = 0;

    static int hayold = -1;
    static int haylen = -1;
    static char haybuf[100];
    if (hay != hayold) {
        haylen = _match_array(hay,haybuf);
        hayold = hay;
        dbgprt(H,"match_array: HAYSET hay=%d haylen=%d\n",hay,haylen);
    }

    static int needold = -1;
    static int needlen = -1;
    static char needbuf[100];
    if (need != needold) {
        needlen = _match_array(need,needbuf);
        needold = need;
        dbgprt(N,"match_array: NEEDSET need=%d needlen=%d\n",need,needlen);
    }

    char *haye = &haybuf[haylen - needlen];
    for (char *hayp = haybuf;  hayp <= haye;  ++hayp) {
        for (int needidx = 0;  needidx < needlen;  ++needidx) {
            match = (hayp[needidx] == needbuf[needidx]);
            dbgprt(L,"match_array: TRY needidx=%d hayp=%d needbuf=%d match=%d\n",
                needidx,hayp[needidx],needbuf[needidx],match);
            if (! match)
                break;
        }
        if (match)
            break;
    }

    return match;
}

#if 0
typedef u32 arg_t;
#else
typedef int arg_t;
#endif

int
match_aman1(arg_t a, arg_t b)
{
    int temp, b_size = 0, tens = 1;

    temp = b;

    // finding total digits in b
    while (temp) {
        b_size++;
        temp /= 10;
    }

    tens = pow(10, b_size);

    while (a) {
        if ((a % tens) == b)
            return 1;
        a /= 10;
    }

    return 0;
}

int
match_aman2(arg_t a, arg_t b)
{
    int temp, b_size = 0, tens = 1;

    temp = b;

    // finding total digits in b
    while (temp) {
        b_size++;
        temp /= 10;
    }

#if 0
    tens = pow(10, b_size);
#else
    for (;  b_size > 0;  --b_size)
        tens *= 10;
#endif

    while (a) {
        if ((a % tens) == b)
            return 1;
        a /= 10;
    }

    return 0;
}

typedef struct {
    int (*tst_fnc)(int hay,int need);
    const char *tst_tag;
    const char *tst_reason;
    int tst_enable;
    tsc_t tst_elap;
} tst_t;
typedef tst_t *tst_p;
typedef const tst_t *tst_pc;

#define TST(_fnc,_reason) \
    { \
        .tst_fnc = _fnc, \
        .tst_tag = #_fnc, \
        .tst_reason = _reason, \
        .tst_enable = 1 \
    }

tst_t tstlist[] = {
    TST(match_strstr,"sprintf/strstr reference"),
    TST(match_strstr2,"sprintf/strstr (cached)"),
    TST(match_array,"decode numbers into arrays"),
    TST(match_array2,"arrays (cached)"),
    TST(match_mod10,"mod10 algorithm"),
    TST(match_aman1,"Aman's original (with pow)"),
    TST(match_aman2,"Aman's modified (multiply)"),
    TST(match_mod10b,"mod10 (with caching)"),
    { .tst_tag = NULL }
};

#define TSTFORALL(_tst) \
    _tst = tstlist;  _tst->tst_tag != NULL;  ++_tst

const char *
tagof(tst_pc tstcur)
{
    const char *cp;
    const char *tag;

    tag = tstcur->tst_tag;

    cp = strrchr(tag,'_');
    if (cp != NULL)
        tag = cp + 1;

    return tag;
}

void
dochk(int hay,int need)
{
    tst_p tstcur;
    tst_p tstold = NULL;
    int oldflg;
    int curflg;
    int fail;

    for (TSTFORALL(tstcur)) {
        curflg = tstcur->tst_fnc(hay,need);

        if (tstold == NULL) {
            tstold = tstcur;
            oldflg = curflg;
        }
        fail = (curflg != oldflg);

        if (dbgok(C) || fail) {
            if (fail)
                XFLUSH;
            printf("%d %d -- %s=%d %s=%d %s\n",
                hay,need,
                tagof(tstold),oldflg,
                tagof(tstcur),curflg,
                fail ? "FAIL" : "PASS");
            if (fail)
                exit(1);
        }

        tstold = tstcur;
        oldflg = curflg;
    }
}

void
dochkall(void)
{
    int hay;

    hay = haylim[0];

    mod10b_redo = 0;
    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 10;  ++iter) {
        for (int need = needlim[0];  need <= needlim[1];  ++need)
            dochk(hay,need);
    }

    tsc_t tscbeg = tscget();

    mod10b_redo = 0;
    for (int need = needlim[0];  need <= needlim[1];  ++need) {
        printf("\rneed: %d ",need);
        hangflg = 1;

        fflush(stdout);
        for (hay = haylim[0];  hay <= haylim[1];  ++hay)
            dochk(hay,need);
    }
    tsc_t tscend = tscget();
    tscend -= tscbeg;

    XFLUSH;
    printf("ELAPSED: %.9f\n",tscsec(tscend));
}

void
dorat(double elap,tsc_t tscold)
{
    double ratio = tscsec(tscold);
    const char *tag;

    ratio /= elap;
    if (ratio < 1.0) {
        tag = "slower";
        ratio = 1.0 / ratio;
    }
    else
        tag = "faster";

    outprt(" (%.3fx %s)", ratio,tag);
}

int
tstcmp(const void *vplhs,const void *vprhs)
{
    tst_pc tstlhs = vplhs;
    tst_pc tstrhs = vprhs;
    tsc_t dif;
    int cmp;

    dif = tstrhs->tst_elap - tstlhs->tst_elap;

    cmp = 0;
    if (dif < 0)
        cmp = -1;
    if (dif > 0)
        cmp = 1;

    dbgprt(D,"tstcmp: DIF %.9f %.9f dif=%lld cmp=%d\n",
        tscsec(tstrhs->tst_elap),tscsec(tstlhs->tst_elap),dif,cmp);

    return cmp;
}

int ratflg;

void
dotsc(tst_p tstcur)
{
    tsc_t tscelap = tstcur->tst_elap;
    static tsc_t tscref;
    static tsc_t tscold;

    if (! ratflg) {
        tscref = tscelap;
        tscold = tscelap;
    }

    double elap = tscsec(tscelap);
    outprt("%.9f %s",elap,tagof(tstcur));

    if (ratflg) {
        dorat(elap,tscold);
        dorat(elap,tscref);
    }

    ratflg = 1;

    if (tstcur->tst_reason != NULL)
        outprt(" -- %s",tstcur->tst_reason);

    outprt("\n");

    tscold = tscelap;
}

void
dotscall(void)
{
    tst_p tstcur;
    tsc_t tscelap;

    outflg = ! opt_q;
    outprt("\n");
    outprt("Unordered:\n");
    ratflg = 0;
    for (TSTFORALL(tstcur)) {
        tsc_t tscbeg = tscget();

        for (int need = needlim[0];  need <= needlim[1];  ++need) {
            for (int hay = haylim[0];  hay <= haylim[1];  ++hay)
                tstcur->tst_fnc(hay,need);
        }

        tscelap = tscget();
        tscelap -= tscbeg;
        tstcur->tst_elap = tscelap;

        dotsc(tstcur);
    }

    int tstcnt = 0;
    for (TSTFORALL(tstcur), ++tstcnt);
    qsort(tstlist,tstcnt,sizeof(tst_t),tstcmp);

    outflg = 1;
    outprt("\n");
    outprt("Sorted:\n");
    ratflg = 0;
    for (TSTFORALL(tstcur))
        dotsc(tstcur);
}

void
rangeget(char *cp,int *lim)
{

    lim[0] = -1;
    lim[1] = -1;

    lim[0] = strtol(cp,&cp,10);
    if (*cp++ == ',')
        lim[1] = strtol(cp,&cp,10);
    else
        lim[1] = lim[0];
}

void
tstopt(char *bp)
{
    static int initflg = 1;
    tst_p tstcur;
    char *cp;
    char **av;
    char *argv[100];
    int negflg;

    av = argv;
    while (1) {
        cp = strtok(bp,",");
        *av = cp;

        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        bp = NULL;
        ++av;
    }

    if (initflg) {
        initflg = 0;

        negflg = 0;
        for (av = argv;  *av != NULL;  ++av) {
            if (strchr(*av,'-') != NULL) {
                negflg = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (TSTFORALL(tstcur))
            tstcur->tst_enable = negflg;
    }

    for (av = argv;  *av != NULL;  ++av) {
        bp = *av;
        cp = strrchr(bp,'-');

        negflg = (cp != NULL);
        if (negflg)
            *cp = 0;

        for (TSTFORALL(tstcur)) {
            const char *tag = tagof(tstcur);
            if (strcmp(tag,bp) == 0) {
                tstcur->tst_enable = ! negflg;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void
dbgopt(char *bp)
{

    if (*bp == 0) {
        memset(opt_d,1,sizeof(opt_d));
        printf("dbgopt: enable all\n");
    }

    for (;  *bp != 0;  ++bp) {
        opt_d[(byte) *bp] = 1;
        printf("dbgopt: enable %c\n",*bp);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'c':  // check mode
            opt_c = ! opt_c;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dbgopt(cp);
            break;
        case 'q':
            opt_q = ! opt_q;
            break;
        case 'T':
            tstopt(cp);
            break;
        }
    }

    do {
        if (argc == 2) {
            rangeget(argv[0],haylim);
            rangeget(argv[1],needlim);
            break;
        }

        rangeget("1,1000000",haylim);
        rangeget("2,99",needlim);
    } while (0);
    printf("HAY: %d %d\n",haylim[0],haylim[1]);
    printf("NEED: %d %d\n",needlim[0],needlim[1]);

    printf("TESTS:");
    tst_p tstrhs;
    tst_p tstlhs = tstlist;
    for (TSTFORALL(tstrhs)) {
        if (! tstrhs->tst_enable)
            continue;
        printf(" %s",tagof(tstrhs));

        if (tstlhs != tstrhs)
            *tstlhs = *tstrhs;
        ++tstlhs;
    }
    printf("\n");
    tstlhs->tst_tag = NULL;

    do {
        if (! opt_c) {
            dotscall();
            break;
        }

        dochkall();
    } while (0);

    dbgprt(N,"DEBUG: mod10b_redo=%d\n",mod10b_redo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using string is not permitted

Comment: @Tom Did you actually read my entire answer? The method I came up with did _not_ use strings, or digit arrays, and _only_ used mod and div in a loop. The `strstr` was just a reference implementation to act as comparison for a diagnostic test.

Answer (score 0):

with [Craig Estey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65765800/14742872)  idea,

By his idea, you can easily code without the array and it will be more efficient. Here I have written the function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int number_within_number(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
    int temp, b_size=0, tens=1;
    temp = b;
    
    // finding total digits in b
    while(temp){
        b_size ++;
        temp/=10;
    }
    
    tens = pow(10,b_size);
    
    while(a){
        if((a%tens) == b)
            return 1;
        a/=10;
    }
    
    return 0;
}


int main(){
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter a: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter b: ");
    scanf("%d",&b); 
    
    if(number_within_number(a,b))
        printf("Yes");
    else
        printf("No");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to include benchmarking. I added a test of your modifications to my algorithm. Unfortunately, your changes slowed things down considerably. In particular, `pow` is _expensive_. Anyway, have a look.

Comment: @AmanKamani Your program took too long to execute in my compiler, and gives the wrong output for certain numbers

Comment: @Tom can you give the test cases where it gives wrong output