# Checking is one number is the part of the other number

Tags: c, numbers

The task is to check if one number is part of the other (input:1035 35 (YES) 1035 53(NO). Why doesn't this method work for (1,0). What is a mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int nwn(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
       unsigned base = 1;
       while (base <= b) base *= 10;

       while (a >= b) {
           if (a % base == b) return 1;
           a /= 10;
       }

       return 0;
}

int main(void) {
      unsigned a, b;
      scanf("%d %d", &a,&b);
      printf("%d", nwn(a,b));
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and step thru it line by line. Examine the flow and variable values as it runs. That's the best way to find out for yourself what the program is doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if one number is contained in other number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765167/check-if-one-number-is-contained-in-other-number)

Comment: The first base to test is 10 which correspond to 1 digit not 1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have tested more cases. But if it's just the b=0 case that's causing trouble, then just add a special case for it. After all, a quick glance at your algorithm gives me reason to believe that zero could be a tricky edge case.

```
int contains_zero(unsigned int a) {
    while(a>0) {
        if(a%10 == 0) return 1;
        a /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}

int nwm(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    if(b == 0) return contains_zero(a);

    // The rest of your code
}
```